# How can I avoid "±" symbol disappearing from my script every time I restart an R session?

Tags: r, paste, symbols

I have used the Plus-minus sign (`±`) several times along a given script, by pasting it directly. For example:

```
paste("Mean", "SD", sep = " ± ")
```

However, when I restart my R session, a `?` symbol appers instead, like this:

```
paste("Mean", "SD", sep = " ? ")
```

What am I doing wrong? should I use a different method to type this symbol in my R script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
paste("Mean", "SD", sep = " \U00B1 ")
```